# How can I access this variable inside of an ActionListener?

Tags: java, actionlistener

```
public class DaysAliveGUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    DaysAliveGUI window = new DaysAliveGUI();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public DaysAliveGUI() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {

        JButton jButton_Calculate = new JButton("Calculate");
        jButton_Calculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent arg0) {

                int iDayBirth = Integer.parseInt(jTextField_DoBDay.getText());
                int iMonthBirth = Integer.parseInt(jTextField_DoBMonth.getText());
                int iYearBirth = Integer.parseInt(jTextField_DoBYear.getText());

                int iDayCurrent = Integer.parseInt(jTextField_CdDay.getText());
                int iMonthCurrent = Integer.parseInt(jTextField_CdMonth.getText());
                int iYearCurrent = Integer.parseInt(jTextField_CdYear.getText());

                double iDaysAlive;

                Calendar caBirthDate = new GregorianCalendar(iYearBirth, iMonthBirth - 1, iDayBirth);
                Calendar caCurrentDate = new GregorianCalendar(iYearCurrent, iMonthCurrent - 1, iDayCurrent);

                iDaysAlive = caCurrentDate.getTimeInMillis() - caBirthDate.getTimeInMillis();
    iDaysAlive = iDaysAlive / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) + 1;
            }
        });

        jButton_Calculate.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 15));
        jButton_Calculate.setBounds(180, 205, 103, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(jButton_Calculate);

        /* Here is the error:
           iDaysAlive cannot be resolved to a variable*/
        JLabel lblDaysAlive = new JLabel("Days Alive: " + iDaysAlive);

        lblDaysAlive.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 18));
        lblDaysAlive.setBounds(135, 257, 147, 21);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblDaysAlive);

    }
}
```

Comment: initialize your variable as global, you can initialize it outside the main. btw, what variable you want to access?

Comment: Create the variables that you want to access, outside the function as global variables in `DaysAliveGUI ` class. Then initialize those variables from inside the function..

Comment: iDaysAlive is the variable im trying to access, i've initialised it outside the main but its returning a value of 0 outside the ActionListener. Yet inside its returning the correct value

Comment: @theSwein, check my asnwer, make your variable as static and implement the getter and setter.

Comment: did your already remove this line `double iDaysAlive;` on your initialize function?, remove that one and transfer it outside the method..

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring iDaysAlive inside the action listener with the line

```
        double iDaysAlive;
```

If it is declared inside the action listener you can't use it outside.

You need to define iDaysAlive somewhere where it can be accessed by the inialize function. I would suggest making it a field of your class.

Answer (score 1):

you can make your variable as a global to make it accessible within the class..

you can initialize your `iDaysAlive` outside the method:

```
public class DaysAliveGUI {
   double iDaysAlive = 0;
public static void main(String[] args) {
 ....
```

you can also make it as a `static variable` and create a `getter` and `setter`

like this:

```
static double iDaysAlive;

 public static void setIDaysAlive(double _iDaysAlive ){
   iDaysAlive = _iDaysAlive;
 }
 public static double getIDaysAlive(){
    return iDaysAlive;
 }
```

and if you want to assign a value, you can make it like this:

```
setIDaysAlive(123);
```

if we're going to implement your formula, it will look like this:

```
setIDaysAlive( caCurrentDate.getTimeInMillis() - caBirthDate.getTimeInMillis() );

setIDaysAlive( getIDaysAlive() / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) + 1 );
```

if you want get the value, you can call it like this:

```
getIDaysAlive();
```

**updated:**
here's where you add the static variable and the getter and setter method:

```
static double iDaysAlive;

  public static void setIDaysAlive(double _iDaysAlive ){
   iDaysAlive = _iDaysAlive;
 }
 public static double getIDaysAlive(){
    return iDaysAlive;
 }
public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    DaysAliveGUI window = new DaysAliveGUI();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: where do i place this piece of code?


static double iDaysAlive;

 public void setIDaysAlive(double iDaysAlive ){
    this.iDaysAlive = iDaysAlive;
 }
 public double getIDaysAlive(){
    return iDaysAlive;
 }

Comment: place that inside the class. you can place that above the main method

Comment: Setting a static variable using `this` seems inherently wrong... You should make the methods static too.

Comment: Ok i've now done that but now for:      

setiDaysAlive(caCurrentDate.getTimeInMillis() - caBirthDate.getTimeInMillis());
    setiDaysAlive(iDaysAlive / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) + 1);

I get the error "The method setiDaysAlive(long) is undefined for the type new ActionListener(){}

Comment: now for: this.iDaysAlive = iDaysAlive; theres an error: cannot use this in a static context

Comment: @theSwein, okay, i'll open my IDE to check it.

Comment: @theSwein, check it now, i rename the parameter variable.  `public static void setIDaysAlive(double _iDaysAlive ){
       iDaysAlive = _iDaysAlive;
    }` and also the getter method. `public static double getIDaysAlive(){
       return iDaysAlive;
    }` check my updated getter and setter method

Comment: Ok that part looks all good now but in the ActionListener im still getting the error: "The method setiDaysAlive(long) is undefined for the type new ActionListener(){}
for the code: setiDaysAlive(caCurrentDate.getTimeInMillis() - caBirthDate.getTimeInMillis());

Comment: try setting this value like this: `setIDaysAlive(12)` if it results the same error:

Comment: still getting an error, i cant even write that without itself getting an error. might head back to the drawing board and start over, thanks for the help, i really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Since you have declared `lblDaysAlive` below action listener it is not accessible within the listener. As suggested by others, make it instance variable by declaring it class scope.

If you still want to declare it in method, try to move the declaration along with `jButton_Calculate`:

```
JButton jButton_Calculate = new JButton("Calculate");
JLabel lblDaysAlive = new JLabel("Days Alive: --");//move here
...
jButton_Calculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent arg0) {
      ...
      lblDaysAlive.setText("Days Alive: " + iDaysAlive);
    }
});
...
```